# OpenGL blending function to elminate primitive overlap but maintain overall opacity

Tags: c++, opengl, openscenegraph

I have some geometry which has a single primitive set that's a tri-strip. Some of the triangles in the primitive overlap, so when I add a material to the geometry with an alpha value I see the overlap (as expected). I want to get rid of this effect without changing the geometry though -- I tried playing around with different blending modes (glBlendFunc()) but I couldn't get this to work. I got some interesting results, but nothing that would eliminate opacity effects within the primitives of the tri strip, and preserve opacity for the entire object. I'm using OpenSceneGraph, but it provides a method to call glBlendFunc() for the geometry in question.

[image]

So from the image, assume that pink roads, purple roads and yellow roads constitute three separate objects, each created using a single tri strip (there are multiple strips, but for arguments sake, pretend that there were only three different colored tri strips here). I basically don't want to see the self intersections within the same color

Also, my question is pretty much the same as this one: [OpenGL, primitives with opacity without visible overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972338/opengl-primitives-with-opacity-without-visible-overlap), but I should note that when I tried the blending mode in accepted answer for that question, the strips weren't rendered in the scene at all.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue in a previous project. Here's how I solved it :

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA)
```

> and draw the rectangles. The idea behind this is that you draw a
>   rectangle with the desired transparency which is taken from the
>   framebuffer, but in the progress mask the area you've drawn to so that
>   your subsequent rectangles will be masked there.

Source : [Stackoverflow : Overlapping rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972338/opengl-primitives-with-opacity-without-visible-overlap)

Comment: I mentioned I tried this in my original post, but the result was that the objects weren't rendered at all.

Comment: @Pris: Did you implement all of the steps? Including writing the alpha to the framebuffer *first*?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After a decent amount of searching, I couldn't really figure out how to do this with OpenSceneGraph. Maybe the title of my question is misleading -- I'm trying to accomplish this with OSG... I had thought it was just a question of which parameters I should be passing to glBlendFunc().

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to render each set of paths to a texture and then draw the texture onto the window with alpha.  You can do this for each color of path.

[This](http://ogltotd.blogspot.com.au/2006/12/render-to-texture.html) outlines the general idea.