# What is the technique to make a bunch of straight lines appear as if they are 1 straight line?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, geometry, 2d

In 2D graphics, 4 straight lines can be drawn; horizontal, vertical, oblique-right, and oblique left.

[image]

The lines in red and blue are represented by `y = x` and `y = -x` respectively. Attempting to graph something  different than that such as `y = 2x` requires drawing multiple straight lines:

[image]

That, despite looking like 1 straight line is made up of multiple vertical straight lines; in order to reveal the visual trick, all we have to do is to zoom in to the picture:

[image]

I want to implement the technique using c++ and winapi, but what is that technique?

Comment: This is not "multiple vertical straight lines". This is called anti-aliasing. And this is something that's implemented by whatever graphical library, toolkit, or API that's used to implement graphics. If you want to "implement the technique using C++ and winapi" then you'll need to do some research into winapi to determine whether, or not, anti-aliasing is supported. Or, perhaps, you're asking about the algorithms that implement anti-aliasing. This should be covered by every textbook on advanced graphical algorithms, did you try to do some research, first?

Comment: [Line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you not see the vertical straight lines? am so confused

Comment: What something appears to be, and what something really is, are sometimes two completely different things. I suggested that what you're seeing is just an antialiasing algorithm. Did you look it up, and did you learn what antialiasing is and how it works?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what i'm seeing is multiple straight vertical lines whose units are of different colors. I get it, it's called anti-aliasing. What is the formula for the colors to produce that visual trick?

Comment: The formula is very simple: for every pixel calculate, to the maximum available precision, what percentage of the pixel is covered by the line. So, for example, if the calculation shows that the upper bound of the line is `y=6.4`, then at `y=6` 40% of the pixel is covered by the line. Then, it's just a linear interpolation between the background color and the line color's RGB values. In this case, 40% from white to red. Mission accomplished. See any good textbook on graphical algorithms for more information on implementing anti-aliasing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik now it makes sense. but if you don't mind me asking one more question: 11 square units make up 1 vertical line in the last figure (2 of which are hard to notice: the ones at the top and bottom). how is this length determined? so if i had a graph for `3x`, what should the length be?

Comment: Insufficient information. It is necessary to know the width of the line too. This looks like a 2 or a 3 pixel-wide line. Not possible to know without looking at the line's actual drawing formula. Then, once that's known, it's a matter of running the calculations. However, the bigger problem here has a well-known technical term: "putting the cart before the horse". First, using one's favorite textbook, work out the formula for using linear interpolation for a line that's one pixel wide. Then, once the algorithm is ***understood***, move to implementing anti-aliasing for x-wide lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there are two types of lines, and the method you use differs between them:

- *thin lines*, which are drawn directly at the pixel level
- *thick lines*, which are drawn by combining primitives like triangles, which are rendered using rasterization

#### Thin Lines

[image: Two rasterized lines. The colored pixels are shown as circles. Above: monochrome screening; below: Gupta-Sproull anti-aliasing]
*Two rasterized lines. The colored pixels are shown as circles. Above: monochrome screening; below: Gupta-Sproull anti-aliasing - by Phrood~commonswiki*

Drawing thin lines happens using specialized algorithms. Usually, the aim is to draw a line which is only one pixel wide.
The algorithm depends on your goals:

- [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is a popular choice for pixel-perfect, very thin lines with no anti-aliasing
- [The Gupta and Sproll algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm#Gupta_and_Sproll_algorithm) produces thin, but smooth (anti-aliased) lines
- ...

*See also: [Line drawing algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm)*

#### Thick Lines

These are easier and harder to render at the same time.
If you don't have to worry about line endings and corners, you just create a quadliteral around the line, and render it using rasterization like everything else.

However, rendering corners and endings requires using multiple primitives typically:
[image: A thick line with a rounded corner consisting of quads, triangles, and a circle]
*A thick line with a rounded corner consisting of quads, triangles, and a circle - by @japreiss*

The red line that you've shared looks like a thick line, because it is multiple pixels thick.

*See also: [Rendering Blended Lines In OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22483198/5740428)*